# NoSuchBucket error sometimes occurs when looping through all S3 buckets

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have written some code meant to loop through all S3 buckets and print each bucket's account, name, and versioning status. This code worked when I ran it yesterday with no errors. Today, it gave me a BucketNotFound error when it reached some bucket. I hadn't changed the code at all except to make the .csv file it outputs to appended instead of overwritten.

```
def main(access_key, access_secret):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=access_secret,
        )
    s3resource = session.resource('s3')
    account = session.client('iam').list_account_aliases()['AccountAliases'][0]
    with open('Buckets with Versioning Enabled.csv', 'a') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(['Account', 'Bucket', 'Versioning'])
        for bucket in s3resource.buckets.all():
            response = s3resource.BucketVersioning(bucket.name).status
            if response is None:
                versioning = "Disabled"
            else:
                versioning = response
            print("Account: " + account + " | Bucket: " + bucket.name + " | Versioning: " + versioning)
            writer.writerow([account, bucket.name, versioning])
```

Can anyone advise me about why this code might selectively throw such an error? This code needs to work reliably. It takes a long time to run this code due to the number of buckets it must check, and it would be frustrating to have to run it multiple times until this error doesn't occur. Here is the exception:

```
botocore.errorfactory.NoSuchBucket: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the GetBucketVersioning operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

Comment: Might it be that the bucket is in a different region? You would need to create another `s3resource` _within_ the `for` loop so that it connects to the specific Region where the bucket lives.

Comment: There should be no need to pass in Access Key and Secret Key. If the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, simply assign an IAM Role to the instance and it will receive credentials. If you are running the code on your own computer, store credentials in a configuration file using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command. In both cases, the code will then automatically find the credentials without needing them to be specified.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for commenting. No, region isn't the issue. The AWS console/CLI doesn't require region specification for accessing S3, and neither does Boto 3. The .csv file shows info was accessed successfully for buckets in different regions. And the keys are handled this way for a reason. The program runs locally and loops through all AWS accounts (yes, it prints the column titles once for every account; I should fix that). The keys for all accounts are stored within an AWS Secret, which another function handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible causes for this, one obvious and one not so obvious until you rememeber that S3 is a massive-scale, globally-distributed system.

If a bucket is deleted after your script fetches the list, that would be the obvious cause.  Since you say you ran the script several times to get past the error, that's probably not the problem here, but definitely something to keep in mind.

The other, less obvious case would be a bucket deleted a few minutes before the script started.  S3 maintains a global list of all bucket names, and that list is replicated to all the regions.  After a bucket is deleted, the index replica being used to service your request may not yet know that the bucket is gone.

It is reasonable to speculate that this condition would *probably* become more likely or last longer under two conditions: the recently-deleted bucket is in a different region than the one you're connecting to, and the region you're connecting to happens to be a region other than us-east-1.  This seems likely because under the hood, us-east-1 is the official keeper of the authoritative bucket list, so either or both of these things could increase the delay before global consistency is achieved. (Note that during the relatively brief us-east-1 outage of 2017, S3 in all other regions functioned almost perfectly, but it wasn't possible to create a bucket in any S3 region).

Either way, you'll need to catch the exception and continue.

Comment: Thank you. It appears that the problem is the global bucket list. Do you know how often this list is updated, or if there is any way to force an update?

Comment: It's continuously updated, automatically, but consistency is eventual, so there is no way to force an update.  As I implied, above, you *might* find that configuring your client to use the us-east-1 region when you fetch the bucket list makes it more likely that the list of buckets you receive is as up to date as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if connecting to us-east-1 helps. Otherwise, I suppose it's not the end of the world if I can't check one bucket out of a few thousand for versioning. I'll just catch the exception and continue.